# How to setup output folder for dmd?

Tags: d, dmd

How to set output folder (obj, ext, etc..) for digital mars compiler (a.k.a. 'dmd') (on windows) in command line (not in Visual D)? I found -of for setting an executable name.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it was simple: -ofPath/To/Your/Out/Folder/ExeName